# Installed Plymouth theme, boot now hangs after grub menu with no details [Manjaro]

Tags: arch-linux, boot, dual-boot, manjaro, plymouth

I decided I wanted to get my hands a little dirty and make a custom Plymouth boot theme. I basically just copied one of the defaults and changed some of the parameters and added my own image.

Now on boot, I get to grub but after selecting Manjaro the screen goes to boot but hangs with the cursor in the top left staying solid. Not able to type or hop into console with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. I have access to the drive because I'm dual-booted with Win11 so could potentially edit files on my linux partition. I also could get a new live boot USB to try to repair, but not sure if any of these are the right way to fix this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could approach fixing this?

---

Manjaro XFCE on Razer Blade RTX 2070 but intel CPU is what handles display (laptop)

Linux Kernel 15.7?? the most recent stable for manjaro.

EDIT:
Thanks to a little push from Bravo I have access to the partition from my Tails USB I carry around. Still have no idea how I should go about removing Plymouth. Gonna try and dive into some documentation.

Comment: *I'm dual-booted with Win11 so could potentially edit files on my linux partition* - in a perfect world this would be nice - but Windows has no way to edit files in a linux partition (I could be wrong, WSL in Windows 11 may well be able to)

Comment: @Bravo thanks for the comment, I found a GitHub repo for an arch linux wsl distro and I'm going to be trying to use that to fix? remove? something? plymouth.

Comment: again, not sure WSL can access a linux partition - you'd be better off using a live boot disk

Comment: @Bravo I have a Tails USB handy would that be a good approach?

Comment: no idea what a tails USB is

Comment: @Bravo live boot Linux, doesn’t write to disk. Made for being anonymous or something. Made it for fun and left it in my bag lol lucky me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Thanks Bravo for the little pushes.

If anyone is curious I just booted into a live linux os (tails), mounted my manjaro partition, and removed ~/.config/plymouth folder. (also made a back up just in case)